# BeautifulSoup get element inside list except one

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get all link value inside a list except one of them.
This is my list:

```
    <ul>    
<li>
  <a class="link" href="consept link 1">
      <svg class="consept" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><use xlink:href="link"></use></svg>
    <h2>Consept title 1</h2>
</a></li>
<li>
  <a class="link" href="consept link 2">
      <svg class="consept" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><use xlink:href="link"></use></svg>
    <h2>Consept title 2</h2>
</a></li>
<li>
  <a class="link" href="consept link 3">
      <svg class="consept" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><use xlink:href="link"></use></svg>
    <h2>Consept title 3</h2>
</a></li>
<li>
  <a class="link" href="video link">
      <svg class="video" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><use xlink:href="link"></use></svg>
    <h2>video title</h2>
</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get link address of parent `<svg class="consept">` I mean the a tag but not svg with class video.

expected result:

```
consept link 1
consept link 2
consept link 3
```

Comment: What if there are multiple `<svg>`s under an `<a>`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem those are icon next to titles. the last svg icon is different. that is video icon

Answer (score 0):

This worked thanks to a friend.

```
def _get_all_links(self):
      consepts = self.section_bs4.select('consept')
      for video_index, post in enumerate(consepts):
          consept_url = post.find_parent('a')['href']
```